Why does the force exerted by a solenoid on a 'Flat face' plunger decrease exponentially with distance?
Consider a typical solenoid with a flat face plunger (typical solenoid design) and its force stroke curve as described here (force stroke curve).
Query: As the plunger protrudes out of the solenoid why does the force (pull/push, depending on the type) decrease exponentially with its distance (the distance is 0 when plunger is completely inside the solenoid)? I am trying to understand it conceptually. Can someone please help? Of course for two point charges, the force b/w them is inversely proportional to the square of distance between them. But I an unclear what happens in the plunger scenario? Why doesn't it decrease linearly?
My background is CS not electrical.

As the graphs you reference show, the curve depends somewhat on the shape of the plunger.  In what one might call the far field its logical that the force is inverse square but in the near field the curve will be somewhat different.  What curve were you expecting and why?

Thanks. I should have mentioned the (B) curve i.e. the flat faced one since it has the maximum holding force. Its the 'logical' or the 'obvious' part I am trying to understand!? :) As the plunger moves out the number of solenoid turns around it decrease linearly. So why isn't it the case that the force decreases linearly as well? I am unclear conceptually at this point.

Visualise the magnetic field lines.  In the pinger were very small and in the middle of the coil then the force might be fairly linear while the plunger remains inside the coil, but as drawn part of the plunger is already outside the coil.  I’m sorry I’m not able to quantify better than that otherwise I would post as an answer.

Thanks for the effort. But its totally unclear to me.

look at section 4, plunger ends, and how they vary the force/stroke curve. Force is change of energy per change of distance. By altering the profile of the meeting faces, you can alter the stored energy versus position curve, and therefore the force versus positiion curve. Those faces are not 'point charges'.

@Neil_UK I didn't compare/imply faces are point charges. I just meant that for example force b/w point charges decreases quadratically with distance (Columb's law). But what is similar reasoning for the flat faced solenoid-plunger behavior is unclear to me.  And I haven't got a self contained answer/explanation yet..

Maybe an approach considering derivative of energy wrt linear motion would work here.. just a suggestion.

can someone please help with this? I thought a standard theoretical Q like this would have an easy answer since electromagnetism is more than 100 years old. But I haven't gotten any!

there's a lot of circles in there, so for every wire width you move out, you lose 3.1 widths worth of transfer. there's also usually a spring which is non-linear and pulls harder and harder the more it's stretched. and then there's the noted invers-square effects. Add it all up and you get the graph.
